# Pre populating host, username, and password for WinSCP login using .cmd file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, winscp

I have created a .cmd file that allows the user to select a number that corresponds to a different set of login credentials for WinSCP thus eliminating the need to memorize login credentials for WinSCP.
In my .cmd file I have set host, username, and password according to the following:

```
SET UID=exampleusername     
SET PWD=examplepassword
SET HOST=examplehost
```

I then proceed to call WinSCP using

```
start WinSCP.exe
```

This opens the login interface:

[image]

The WinSCP interface is called correctly but I am having issues coding in my .cmd file to populate the Host Name, User name, and Password fields using the variables defined in my .cmd file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot populate the WinSCP login dialog from a command-line.

All you can do is to have WinSCP open the session directly by calling it like:

```
start WinSCP.exe sftp://%UID%:%PWD%@%HOST%/
```

References:

- [Opening a session from a command-line](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#session)
- [Session URL syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url)

---

Anyway, I do not see why you implement batch-file menu for opening sessions on WinSCP. Did you consider [pre-configuring stored sites for WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/custom_distribution#preconfigured_site) instead?

---

*Btw, you are using some really ancient version of WinSCP (5 years old at least). You need to upgrade urgently.*

Comment: Thanks @Martin. I appreciate the help.